# WordPress W3 Total Cache Minify - JS and CSS Files Not Created (nginx)

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, nginx, w3-total-cache

I have a WordPress site I'm trying to minify with W3 Total Cache.  It runs on nginx on Ubuntu 12.04.

- I am in **manual** minify mode
- In the minify settings, I have the `Rewrite URL structure` option OFF.  It doesn't work either way, but this method needs less nginx config.

When I load the site, it tells WP to load from the following path:

`/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/minify.php?file=5fe99/default.include-body.baf22c.js`

Likewise, had I turned `Rewrite URL structure` ON, that path would be:
`/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/5fe99/default.include-body.baf22c.js`

That file does not exist and it 404's if you try to go to it.

Looking at that directory, I have:

`~/public_html/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/5fe99$ ls -lah
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Jun 26 08:51 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4.0K Jun 26 08:51 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   13 Jun 26 08:51 default.include-body.js.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   13 Jun 26 08:23 default.include.css.id.old`

**Other potential solutions:**

- I've tried recursively doing a `chmod 777` on the entire cache directory, but it just never creates this file, nor does it report an error.
- I've successfully installed and used yui-compressor and Oracle Java, but the file still doesn't get created with that either.  So I know it's not a JSMin problem.

**Contents of local nginx.conf file:**

When `Rewrite URL structure` is OFF, this is all that is requested:

`# BEGIN W3TC Minify cache
    location ~ /home/MY_HOME_DIR/public_html/wp-content/cache/minify.*\.js$ {
        types {}
        default_type application/x-javascript;
        expires modified 31536000s;
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    location ~ /home/MY_HOME_DIR/public_html/wp-content/cache/minify.*\.css$ {
        types {}
        default_type text/css;
        expires modified 31536000s;
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    location ~ /home/MY_HOME_DIR/public_html/wp-content/cache/minify.*js\.gzip$ {
        gzip off;
        types {}
        default_type application/x-javascript;
        expires modified 31536000s;
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    }
    location ~ /home/MY_HOME_DIR/public_html/wp-content/cache/minify.*css\.gzip$ {
        gzip off;
        types {}
        default_type text/css;
        expires modified 31536000s;
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    }
    # END W3TC Minify cache`

**Another error:**

Meanwhile, I also get this error:

`Recently an error occurred while creating the CSS / JS minify cache: A group configuration for "include-body" was not set.`

The plugin author has reported this as a frequent false positive, but that was two years ago.  I'm not sure what that means, there's not much good information on it.

So... has *anyone* ever gotten file minification to work with W3 Total Cache on nginx?  Thanks!

Comment: Hah - this has received a "popular question badge" and not a single person has added a comment or answer. Guess I'm not alone here in not knowing how W3TC's minify works. I never did figure it out.

Comment: I just got this message starting today as well: "Recently an error occurred while creating the CSS / JS minify cache: A group configuration for "include-body" was not set."  Don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

I have partly fixed the issue by making sure that:

1) The `nginx.conf` file was updated to the last options choices.

This means, every time one changes minification options, he has to go to

> http://www.domain.tld/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_install

and copy the nginx sample config and overwrite the current `nginx.conf`

2) Nginx new config is reloaded or Nginx is restarted:

```
nginx -s reload
```

or

```
service nginx restart
```

3) Uncheck the "Rewrite URL structure" option in the W3TC Minify page.

This is going to make generated pages a tiny bit less performing but I have not found a real workaround that works on all my websites.

Comment: The 3) step fixed the issue for me. Thank you very much! You save me tons of hours :)

Comment: Step 3 fixed the issue for me too. Thank !